# Will a iTunes test User work on an app created on a different developer account

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect

I have created an iTunes test User account from My Developer account.

[image]

My client has set up (on a different developer account) an application and in-app-purchase product.

Will I be able to use my test user to purchase the product the client has set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no - you can not.

Test users are restricted to buying content in the sandbox for Products on the Developer account they were created on.

I managed to get a friend to help me test this and got this error when I used his test user.

[image]